# How to detect a specific console output?

Tags: console, console.log, device-detection

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/UAParser.js/0.7.19/ua-parser.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var ua = new UAParser();
    var result = ua.getResult();

    console.log(result.device);


</script>
```

This code gets the name of the device used by a user and displays it in the console. How do I use that information to display a different webpage depending on the device used? If the device is not a mobile device it doesn't display anything in the console. I only want it to go to a different page when it is a mobile device. I need this so I can show a mobile version of my website when the user is using a mobile device.

(Code is not mine got it from here: https://codewithmark.com/mobile-detect)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (result.device.model != undefined){document.location="https://google.com";}
```

Comment: Please share more details. How is this code even related to the console?